# Meaning of the word "induces" and its usage in mathematical prose.

Tags: group-theory, notation

For the word "induce", I often see it used in the context of mapping, as in the included example.  Can someone tell me what this word mean in a mathematical context and how it is used please.

Example:

Let $H$ and $K$ be normal subgroups of the group $G$.  Verify that if the natural mapping $\text{nat}_{K}:G\rightarrow {G/K},$  $\textbf{induces}$ an isomorphism of $H$ onto $G/K$, then $G=H\oplus K.$

Thank you in advance

Comment: See also [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induced_homomorphism). In your example, the surjective homomorphism $\pi\colon g\mapsto gK$ is assumed to induce an isomorphism $\pi_{\mid H}\colon  H \xrightarrow{\cong} G/K$.

Comment: Something "induces" something else when this latter is defined based on the former.

Comment: @DietrichBurde in the Wikipedia article you linked, how does one decide what the canonical map is suppose to be?

Comment: @Devo can you elaborate more about how one can tell when the something later is defined based on the former?

Comment: Seth, this depends on the context. For groups, one could answer:"you need to take the only reasonable choice". Example: The injective ring homomorphism $\iota\colon \Bbb Z\rightarrow \Bbb Q$ induces an isomorphism $\Bbb Z\cong \iota(\Bbb Z)$". By the homomorphism lemma, $G/\ker(\iota)\cong \iota(G)$, so we only have one choice, because $\ker(\iota)$ is trivial, since $\iota$ is injective.

Comment: For example, the restriction of a map to a subset of the domain is a distinct map from the "parent" one, but clearly "induced" by it.

Comment: @Devo so an inclusion map is induced by restricting the domain of a parent function?

Comment: @DietrichBurde what you are saying is that a map can be insured when including extra machinery in the form of the homomorphism lemma in conjunction with the original homomorphism.  So an isomorphism is induced by a surjective homomorphism if the domain of the original map by its kernel is isomorphic to its homomorphic image.

Comment: Take a map $f\colon X\to Y$ and a subset $S\subset X$. Then $g\colon S\to Y$ defined by $g(s):=f(s)$ is "induced by $f$". More informatively, $g=f_{|S}$.

Comment: @Devo isn't that restriction of a function?  Also, when using the word "induced" or the phrase "induced homomorphism", do I have to also state by what additional theorem/lemma along with the original homomorphism that the new homomorphism is created from?

Comment: Seth, the homomorphism lemma is no extra machinery here, but just the context. If you are saying, a natural number "induces" a prime factorization, then the definition of primes is no extra machinery, but just the necessary context.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I am getting the impression that the new homomorphism is created from the original one when I see the word "induces".  Am I right that the new homomorphism can be created because of some mathematical reason?

Comment: Yes, and restriction is an example of "induction". Just an example. Try to formally define the isomorphism in your post, and I expect that its definition will involve $\operatorname{nat}_K$. So, $\operatorname{nat}_K$ "induces" that isomorphism.

Comment: @Devo the isomorphism needed involves the restriction $G$ to $H$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I know in category theory, it is explain in a more technical manner.  I am not that advanced in category theory and I am trying to ask for explanations that can be given in non categorical language if that is possible.

Comment: @Seth why are you asking me? All I did was edit the post to correct your misuse of "it's" and of $\otimes$. I'm not in the conversations you are having.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin ah kk. Sorry. I thought you were the one who closed the post.  My bad.